# Push files from Android to PC over ADB

Tags: android, logging, adb

It's probably not possible due to safety issues and many other reasons, but it's worth a shot, so here goes:

**Is it possible to push files from an Android device directly to a computer using ADB?**

Why would you want that, you might ask. Good question. I find it useful to view larger `Strings` on a computer instead of on an Android device, especially since `Log.d()` won't show `Strings` of a length more of a couple hundred characters. Things like SOAP requests and responses, other xml files are not easily viewable on my Nexus 7. I've tried some things with the `UsbManager` class and the `UsbDevice` class, but I can't seem to find the USB-connection to my computer.

PS. I can think of other methods, like using a logging webservice, for all I care, or writing a script which pulls a certain (log) directory periodically, but I'm just curious whether or not it is possible, it makes my life ever so slightly easier.

Comment: I am able to save a String with about 4.000 characters via `Log.i()`. From Eclipse you can export selected Log statements to a file.

Comment: Yeah, couple'eh hundred, 4.000, it doesn't make much of a difference when receiving 2.000.000 character SOAP responses. and exporting selected Log statements is limited to the 4.000 characters.

Comment: You obviously do not understand how `adb` works. You can't initiate any transfers from the device side. I mean you could but there will be no software on PC side expecting it.

Comment: @AlexP. You obviously did not read my post. If you read it, you'd see that I do not expect it to be possible, but "it's worth a shot". So why my curiosity is worth a downvote, I do not understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I can read in your question, you are quite aware of the fact that you can pull files from your Android device to your PC, so I won't suggest that.

To answer your question: **No**, this is not possible. It's not how `adb` works. Even if you could "push" from Android to PC, you need a piece of software to handle the data. Android does not contain any API which makes that possible, and neither does any part of the Android SDK.

Still you could use any of the methods you already know of (`adb pull`, Eclipse DDMS View, and yes, even a logging webservice, as you yourself suggested).

Hope this clarifies a bit.

Answer (score 0):

To copy a file or directory (and its sub-directories) from the emulator or device, use

```
adb pull <remote> <local>
```

For more details on the usage, refer [this](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/adb.html#copyfiles) link

EDIT: What I understand is that you want your app to pull a particular file right? If yes, you need to use

```
public class YourAppCode {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();
        Process process = runtime.exec(new String[] {"/usr/bin/adb", "devices");
    }
}
```

Instead of devices, you need to send pull command along with the source and destination.

Comment: As you could've read, I do know about pulling and pushing, but I want to specifically push from the Android device to the pc (the Android device should initiate).

Comment: I didn't do it, neither do I understand it. However, as you could've already read, I am quite aware of adb pulling, and I do it quite frequently as well. My specific question was whether or not adb can work in the other direction, that is android -> pc instead of the other way around.

Answer (score 0):

You can push files from ADB to PC (eclipse).

In Eclipse **Window-Open Perspective-DDMS**

and then in DDMS view select your device from the left side list.

and in the Right side view, you will find a folder called **mnt**, inside it you will find sd card. There are your files. your devices files. Now to get them out to your pc

There are two buttons on the right side top. 
one button says **pull a file from device**
another button says **push a file to device**

You need pull the file from device.
Select your respective file and click the **pull a file from device** button.

Comment: I can't access the device in Eclipse. Every link to the SDCard has no folders (`/mnt/sdcard/`, `/sdcard/`, `/storage/emulated/sdcard0/`).

Comment: is your device rooted..?

Comment: if your device is rooted follow the answer in the link I gave. Hope it works.